# Error in process sentinel: No error or warning to show

Tags: auctex

I am receiving the above error when trying to compile a LaTeX document in emacs 24.5, using auctex 11.89.3. Previously, I would get either "Run LaTeX again", or "Compiled successfully". This happened after I updated some packages yesterday, and I am unable to fix it. I did not pay attention to which packages were updated, and I also deleted the obsolete packages immediately, so I do not know what is causing this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you reported was probably triggered by having `TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run` set to non-nil and `TeX-debug-warnings` and/or `TeX-debug-bad-boxes` set to nil.

This should be fixed now in development version of AUCTeX:  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=88fbf8021c7da3c2bf14a646663bd0eb0ccc1448  It'll go live in next ELPA release.  If you want to keep `TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run` set to non-nil, as a workaround (but I find this a good practice in general) you can activate parsing of warnings and bad-boxes:

```lisp
(setq TeX-debug-warnings t
      TeX-debug-bad-boxes t)
```

---

Background on the origin of the error: in AUCTeX 11.89.3 has been introduced the possibility to ignore certain warnings that can be considered too noisy.  This is controlled by two options:

- `TeX-ignore-warnings`: this controls which warnings should be ignored (usually it's a regexp)
- `TeX-suppress-ignored-warnings`: this tells AUCTeX whether to actually ignore those warnings.

In this way one can interactively toggle visibility of ignored warnings with <kbd>x</kbd> in TeX error overview (and toggle visibility of all warnings and bad-boxes with <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>b</kbd>, respectively), but this also requires building of the error/warning list to be shown on-the-fly. Instead, before the fix mentioned above TeX sentinels were looking to the static full list of errors and warnings.

Comment: Thanks. This does solve the problem.  I had - TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run non-nil and TeX-debug-warnings as well as TeX-debug-bad-boxes set to nil. I have changed the latter two to non-nil, and now the file compiles fine (though I now have to dismiss the bad-box warnings every time I compile). Hope, this is fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same behaviour after updating AUCTeX to version 11.89.3. As a workaround I disabled the option TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run.